# Would a neuralizer work on someone who couldn't see?

Tags: movie, men-in-black

If one of the Men In Black used a [neuralizer](http://blog.softwareinsider.org/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/men-in-black-neuralizer.jpg) on someone who couldn't see (or blinked), would it still work?

I don't think we ever see it happen in the movies, but they're based on a [series of comics](http://meninblack.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_The_Men_in_Black_Comics) from the 90s so maybe it's been addressed in one of them?

Comment: I looked away when the clip was playing and I can remember the whole thing

Comment: I kept my eyes open during the clip and...wait...what was the question again?

Comment: Depends on what causes that person to be blind. Eye damage, neural damage or brain damage? Also, the blind person didn't see anything so the question isn't if you could, it's if you'd need to.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes and no. On several occasions we see Agent J covering his eyes with his arm/hands (or simply closing his eyes hard) in order to prevent himself being neuralyzed by Agent K. Since the flash seems to last about half a second, blinking probably wouldn't help you, but covering your eyes (or being blind) certainly would.

[image]

Note that you're only talking about the portable 1990s version. The 1960s version seems to have functioned more like an MRI and may be able to neuralyse those that can't see.

[image]

Answer (score -4):

Yes because it goes into the brainwaves and burrows the memories into a bit of the brain that is hard to get to

Comment: But how does it get "into the brainwaves" if you can't see it?